# Perform a method on specified time

Tags: ios

Is it possible to perform a @selector on specified time?

** I **don't need** id to run it when the app is closed, only when it is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [NSTimer's `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a), and I've linked the Apple documentation for you.

At the same time, if you want to set a *reeeeally* specific time & date, you can reset the NSTimer fire date & time by using [NSTimer's setFireDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/setFireDate%3a) method (where you can pass in a date & time to an already created timer instance).